# Node-sass error in AWS Lambda using RollupJS

Tags: aws-lambda, node-sass, rollup, rollupjs

I'm using serverless to create a Lambda (Node 10x).
The Lambda uses Rollup to create JS and CSS assets. But it is failing at the Rollup stage.

It runs locally using Node 10.0.0 and serverless-offline but once it gets to production, I get this error

```
2019-08-29T14:32:35.254Z        ERROR   error: { Error: Missing binding /var/task/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
- OS X 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
at error (/var/task/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:224:15)
at /var/task/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:17213:17
code: 'PLUGIN_ERROR',
plugin: 'postcss',
id: '/var/task/src/css/app.scss' }
```

I can run `npm rebuild node-sass` locally and it does *something* to my node_modules and makes it bigger, too big in fact to deploy to AWS!

So before I go and rip things out of the app to try and get it to compile at a smaller size, is there anything else I can do regarding this node-sass environment issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Solved it!**

In `node_modules/node-sass/vendor/` there was only a `darwin-x64-64/binding.node` folder/file.

From [this github page](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases) I downloaded [linux-x64-64__binding.node](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.12.0/linux-x64-64_binding.node)

renamed it to `binding.node` and created a `linux-x64-64` folder and put it in there: `node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node`

Then redeployed the lambda and all is well. I just need to remember to do that if/when I do a yarn update or similar.